# How to create a json web token from angular?

Tags: angular, jwt

My question is, I can create a `jwt` from angular, there is a library in angular that allows me to do this, at the moment I am using `@auth0/angular-jwt` for the library and according to what I investigate in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt), the only functions that exist are:

```
const decodedToken = helper.decodeToken(myRawToken);
const expirationDate = helper.getTokenExpirationDate(myRawToken);
const isExpired = helper.isTokenExpired(myRawToken);
```

I can't find one that is similar to `jwt.sign(...)` from `jsonwebtoken`. So I want to know if there is a library that allows me to do this, and if the only one is `jsonwebtoken`, how can I implement it in angular?

Comment: Aren’t JWTs supposed to be generated on a server…? Why would you want to do this on the client side??

Comment: @esqew 
to send sensitive data that I do not want to be seen from the client to the server, for example the email and password at the time of login

Comment: You don’t want to send login details to the server? How can you possibly authenticate in that scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going back and forth I realized that it is unnecessary to generate a token in the front, anyone with minimal knowledge can decipher it and use the information, even so I investigated the procedure to generate a signed token using only the `Crypto-js` library.

The first thing is to install the dependencies:

```
npm i --save crypto-js @types/crypto-js
```

The following will be to create a method that converts our information to a `base64`:

```
base64url(source: any) {
    let encodedSource = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(source);

    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/=+$/, '');

    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\+/g, '-');
    encodedSource = encodedSource.replace(/\//g, '_');

    return encodedSource;
  }
```

Then I will have to create the method to generate the unsigned token:

```
  encodeToken(payload:any) {
    var header = {
      "alg": "HS256",
      "typ": "JWT"
    };

    var stringifiedHeader = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(header));
    var encodedHeader = this.base64url(stringifiedHeader);

    var stringifiedData = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(payload));
    var encodedData = this.base64url(stringifiedData);

    var token = encodedHeader + "." + encodedData;
  }
```

And finally a method that signs the token with our secret key:

```
  signToken(payload:any,key:string) {
    var secret = key;
    let token:any = this.encodeToken(payload);

    var signature:any = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(token, secret);
    signature = this.base64url(signature);

    var signedToken = token + "." + signature;
    return signedToken;
  }
```

In order to call it, I only consume `signToken()` sent as the first argument the object to hide and the second is the key to sign the token.

Comment: Shouldn't the encodeToken method return the token?

Answer (score 0):

If a user writes a password in your app, doesn´t make sense to hide that from them, if you want that information to be hidden from the users in the same network, that is done automatically in production with the SSL certificates (most likely you'll deal with this at deployment, SSL encrypts all the data between user and server in a way you barely feel it).

Basically you get almost nothing from doing that approach, instead you should create jwt server side where you secret keys are safe.

Answer (score -1):

*Please read carefully how JWT is working, especially how the security is achieved and in which conditions.*

Generating a JWT token on the browser makes no sense as it would mean having the private secret key used to sign somewhere in the browser (JS code), thus making it accessible super easily for anyone which would then be able to create tokens by themselves with any data and your server would trust them.

**In your case email and password at login time must be send as is but through a HTTPS connection.**